# How to use nested queries to match all terms in NEST fluent DSL

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to use Elastic Search's .NET API NEST in order to query my elastic datastore.

I got seriously stuck trying to query a nested object's property.

You see when i want to check if the field has one of my terms i will use something like this:

```
q
.Nested(c => c
    .Name("named_query")
    .Boost(1.1)
    .InnerHits(i=>i.Explain())
    .Path(p=>p.CuratedTags)
    .Query(nq => nq
        .Terms(t => t
            .Field(f => f.CuratedTags.First().Name)
            .Terms("lorem", "ipsum")
        )
    )
    .IgnoreUnmapped()
)
```

This will match tags in the tag array that have either the word lorem or ipsum.

What i want is to be able to find results that in their tag array have BOTH lorem AND ipsum. By the looks of it there isn't an operator option at the term level which i can use and set to AND.

I already tried things like Bool Must/Should/Filter.

There doesn't seem to be anything in the NEST documentation that matches what i want.

My object looks like this in elastic:

```
"objectOptions": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "optionId": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "objectId": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
```

And an instance of it:

```
"objectOptions": [
            {
              "objectId": 99,
              "optionId": 249
            },
            {
              "objectId": 99,
              "optionId": 261
            },
            {
              "objectId": 99,
              "optionId": 1267
            },
            {
              "objectId": 99,
              "optionId": 2918
            }
          ]
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nested-query-usage.html#_fluent_dsl_example_52) NEST docs for nested query syntax?

Comment: @Rob as you can see in my question that is exactly what i referenced and it didn't work because my object is an array of a nested object, not just an array of things. However i changed my object's structure and after some hacking around it looks like if you create a bool must with multiple terms that contain a single value each then you can do what i wanted to do.

Comment: @Elfocrash to do `term` AND `term` AND `term`, you need to build a `bool` query with 3 `term` queries in `must` clauses (or 3 `filter` clauses if scoring is not important). NEST provides operator overloading to make this easier to build: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html